# Place Logic In Client Side or Server Side

Tags: web-development, web-applications

I'm building a small personal website. Basically, they are 20 short sound files. Clicking a button will play one of those files randomly. Once played, that file will no longer be played. So in total, the user clicks the button 20 times, each time getting a new random sound.

My question is should the frontend (angularjs) keep track of this list of sound files or should it be done in the backend.

**Frontend Approach**

- An array of file names is populated from an initial server call
- When the 'Play' button is clicked, a name is selected randomly from the list
- A server call is made to get this soundfile, e.g. `getSoundFile('abc.mp3')`
- That filename is then removed from the list

OR

**Backend Approach**

- A collection is initially populated with sound file names
- When the 'Play' button is clicked, a server call is made to get a random sound file, e.g. `getRandomSound()`
- The server randomly selects a filename in this collection, removes it from the collection, finds the corresponding file and returns it to the browser.

Are there pros / cons to each approach? Personally, I would prefer to keep the front-end as light as possible so I am leaning toward the backend approach but I'm wondering if I am overlooking something that would make the frontend approach preferable. Thanks.

EDIT: Question title changed to reflect correct terminology

Answer (score 1):

Frontend and backend are not synonyms for client side and server side.

Indeed you can have a frontend and backend without a server being involved at all.

Regardless of the terminology, the big issue I see here is state. When you remove from the list you aren't being simply random anymore. You're doing a shuffle. That requires that you remember what's been removed.

That causes me to ask an important question: How long do you need this removal to be remembered? Can we start over if the user reloads the page? Do we need to remember from session to session?

I can see the choice you're struggling with impacting your ability to remember state in a few different ways. Make sure you're comfortable with how that choice limits you before you set it in stone.

Comment: Thanks for replying, and for advising me on the correct terminology. Yes I was referring to client side and server side. State isn't a concern. Yes, if the page is reloaded, we start over. There are no user profiles or accounts. No session cookies or anything like that. It is basically as simple as I described in the question: 20 sounds, each click of a button plays a random sound, no sound can be repeated, total of 20 clicks. No further requirements or functionality.